# Filter output and obtain exit code at the same time of an program in Linux shell

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I am running a job in Jenkins(Jenkins is an open source continuous integration tool) by executing a list of shell commands. One of the command is to run a Java program which does some data validation. If  meets with invalid date, the Java program will exit with a none-zero exit code so that Jenkins can discover that this time the build fails.

Unfortunately the Java program prints too much log to stdout and stderr, only a few of them are useful. Since the Java program can not be modified, I decide to filter the output with *grep*. So I wrote the shell as:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH MetaValidatorMain | grep -v "useless keyword1"| grep -v "useless keyword2"
```

But the problem is that, after the execution of the line of shell, the parent process(Jenkins) got exit code of *grep* indead of *java*, so that Jenkins could not determine whether the build was success.

I also tried this:

```
(java -cp $CLASSPATH MetaValidatorMain || exit 1) | grep -v "useless keyword1"| grep -v "useless keyword2"
```

also did not work.

Could anyone tell me how could I write the line of shell to filter output and obtain the right exit code at the same.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways of doing this. However your current setup should work. The reason here being that the grep won't match anything if the command fails, so grep will return with status `1` (unless the program always shows that text no matter what).

### Pipefail

The first way is to set the `pipefail` option. This is the simplest and what it does is basically set the exit status `$?` to the exit code of the last program to exit non-zero (or zero if all exited successfully).

```
# false | true; echo $?
0
# set -o pipefail
# false | true; echo $?
1
```

### $PIPESTATUS

Bash also has a variable called `$PIPESTATUS` which contains the exit status of all the programs in the last command.

```
# true | true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0 0
# false | true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
1 0
# false | true; echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
1
# true | false; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0 1
```

You can use the 3rd command example to get the specific value in the pipeline that you need.

*This solution might not be available though. I think `$PIPESTATUS` might have been added in a fairly recent version of bash, and your OS may not have it.*

### Separate executions

This is the most unwieldy of the solutions. Run each command separately and capture the status

```
# java -cp $CLASSPATH MetaValidatorMain > /tmp/outfile.txt 2>&1
# RETURN_CODE=$?
# grep -v "useless keyword1" /tmp/outfile | grep -v "useless keyword2"
# exit RETURN_CODE
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a long way round, but you could redirect the program output to a file, capture the return and then grep the output file for the content you want:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH MetaValidatorMain > /tmp/outfile.txt 2>&1
RETURN_CODE=$?
grep -v "useless keyword1" /tmp/outfile | grep -v "useless keyword2"
exit RETURN_CODE
```

Comment: Really bit of a long way round, but if works, and the code is quite clear. thx